# How to initialize remote resource accessors modules in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

It would be nice to have some constructor-functions to run synchronously. Consider the following DAO module:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

FooDao = function(mongoUrl) {
  var self = this;
  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, database) {
    if(err) throw err;
    self.foos = database.collection("foos");
  })
};

FooDao.prototype.findById = function(id, callback) {
  this.foos.findOne({"id": id}, callback)
};

FooDao.prototype.save = function(foo, callback) {
  this.foos.update({"id":foo.id}, foo, {upsert:true, w: 1}, callback)
};

exports.FooDao = FooDao;
```

Its user may contain the following code:

```
var FooDao = require('./foo-dao').FooDao;
var fooDao = new FooDao(mongoUrl);
fooDao.findById(42, function(err, foo) {
  if (!err)  console.log(foo);
});
```

This code fails immediately because `FooDao` hasn't yet completed connection to MongoDB.

Is there a way to implement `FooDao` constructor to make the code pass?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466782/make-javascript-method-wait-for-constructor-to-complete Isn't this the answer?

Comment: not really: I need to evaluate the code just once, but with callbacks I'll have to clutter my code with callbacks every time I use the MongoClient API, just to make sure the connection happened.